# LibGDX in C# WPF/WinForms Container

Tags: c#, java, wpf, winforms, libgdx

I have a simple game written in Java which runs on [LibGDX](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/).

However, I am making an editor for the game which is written in C# using WPF for the UI. I need to add a preview pane which will show the actual game (running inside a WPF or WinForms container).

If LibGDX was written in a .Net language, this would not be an issue, but as it is written in Java I do not know how to go about placing the game inside a WPF container.

I have had two possible solutions:

- Use IKVM to convert the game .jar file and the LibGDX .jar files to .Net DLLs. Although I can successfully use IKVM to convert Java to .Net and call functions, I have no way (that I know of) to place a Java control or LibGDX game in a WPF/WinForms container.
- Somehow load the WPF DDLs in Java, make LibGDX draw to a WPF container there, convert the Java code to .Net using IKVM and then in C# call the WPF container from Java. This method seems very tedious and I am not sure that it would even work.

So, how would I go about running a LibGDX game inside a C# WPF or WinForms container?

Comment: Maybe I could implement the editor as a separate library using something like this.. http://www.badlogicgames.com/wordpress/?p=2087